# Cancel animation, stop applyTransformation running

Tags: android, android-animation

I've created a extension to the Animation class in order to create a background fade out animation. I start the animation after pressing a ListView row item. If I press one after another I want to cancel the first animation and start the second. But a bug that I'm having is when I press fast one row after another the animation doesn't stop. After debugging I've noticed that the `applyTransformation` method keeps running for the first animation. I've decided to override the cancel function, but how do I stop the transformation?

```
public BackgroundAnimation(View view, int color){
    this.view = view;
    setDuration(4000L);

    red = Color.red(color);
    blue = Color.blue(color);
    green = Color.green(color);
}
@Override
public void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,Transformation t){
    //super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb((int) ((1 - interpolatedTime) * 255), red, green, blue));

}
```

Comment: have you tried clearAnimation()?

Comment: it should work, why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: no idea, I thought I've implemented my custom animation class not as it should be. or not fully !?

Comment: so interpolatedTime goes always 0 -> 1?

Comment: the method keeps running with interpolatedTime 0 if I run the cancel method. if I call the clearAnimation than yes it runs from 0 -> 1.

Comment: strange, very strange, try cancel & reset

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, `interpolatedTime` would run 0 -> 1 then infinitely repeat for 0.  My solution was to `clearAnimation` in an `AnimationListener`.  It doesn't seem like you should have to do this, but oh well.

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        animationTarget.clearAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
});
```

Comment: I am using the same solution, but it seems ridiculous to me that we have to cancel it manually after we already defined the duration and maybe set the repetition to 0.